# How can I centralize authentication of an AzureResourceManager and write testable classes that use it?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, code-quality, azure

I have to update app code running in a container on AKS to use a WorkloadIdentityCredential. I have to test code that I update in order to pass CI quality gates.

The code uses a `public final` class, `com.azure.resourcemanager.AzureResourceManager`, whose constructors are `private`.

The only way to get a new instance of this ARM class is by authenticating first, by calling the `public static` method `AzureResourceManager.authenticate(tokenCredential, azureProfile)...`.
After retrieving an authenticated instance, the code can access Azure resources through their managers, like `arm.storageAccounts()`, or `arm.virtualMachineScaleSets()`

Problems I see are...

1. I have to refactor `MyClass` to accept an `AzureResourceManager` so that I can mock it and write unit tests.
2. The code is authenticating to the same Azure subscription multiple times.

Will the following code solve my problem? Is there a better way?

```
// In MyClass.java
public class MyClass {
  AzureResourceManagerWrapper armWrapper;
  public MyClass(AzureResourceManagerWrapper armWrapper) {
    this.armWrapper = armWrapper;
  }

  public Object doStuff(){
    // Now I can call methods on this.armWrapper.
    // It's (a little) easier to test and I haven't re-authenticated.
    return new Object();
  }
}

// In MyClassTest.java
public class MyClassTest {
  @Test
  public void testMyClass() throws Exception {
    StorageAccount mockStorageAcct = mock(FakeStorageAccountImpl.class);
    AzureResourceManagerWrapper mockArmWrapper = mock(AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl.class);
    when(mockArmWrapper.storageAccounts_getByResourceGroup(
      "environment-region-zone-storage", "account_name"))
      .then((Answer<StorageAccount>) invocation -> mockStorageAcct);

    // Assert things...
  }
}

class FakeStorageAccountImpl implements StorageAccount {
  public FakeStorageAccountImpl() { /* do nothing */ }

  // ...
  // ...
  // holy moly there a lot of methods to stub...
}


// In AzureResourceManagerWrapper.java
public interface AzureResourceManagerWrapper {
  VirtualMachineScaleSet virtualMachineScaleSets_getByResourceGroup(String resourceGroup, String name);

  StorageAccount storageAccounts_getByResourceGroup(String resourceGroup, String name);
}

// In AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl.java
public class AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl implements AzureResourceManagerWrapper {
  private static AzureResourceManager arm;

  public AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl(TokenCredential tc, AzureProfile ap) {
    if (AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl.arm == null) { // Authenticate only once
      AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl.arm = AzureResourceManager.configure().authenticate(tc, ap).withDefaultSubscription();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public VirtualMachineScaleSet virtualMachineScaleSets_getByResourceGroup(String resourceGroup, String name) {
    return arm.virtualMachineScaleSets().getByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, name);
  }

  @Override
  public StorageAccount storageAccounts_getByResourceGroup(String resourceGroup, String name) {
    return arm.storageAccounts().getByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, name);
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

I was working on a fix for this, but fortunately ManagedCredential in azure-identity v1.4.6 and v1.9.0 both use the [AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-identity_1.4.6/sdk/identity/azure-identity/src/main/java/com/azure/identity/ManagedIdentityCredential.java#L31) environment variable, so I can avoid this work.

For those interested, the path I was taking was to add a constructor to MyClass and use Mockito's ArgumentCaptor. The code below is unfinished (because I can avoid the work) but hopefully it helps someone facing a similar issue.

```
// AzureResourceManagerWrapper.java
public interface AzureResourceManagerWrapper {
  AzureResourceManager getInstance(TokenCredential tc, AzureProfile ap);
}

// AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl.java
public class AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl implements AzureResourceManagerWrapper {
  private AzureResourceManager arm;

  public AzureResourceManager getInstance(TokenCredential tc, AzureProfile ap) {
    // NOTE: This can't be tested without the authenticate method making a network call.
    if (this.arm == null) { // Authenticate only once
      this.arm = AzureResourceManager.configure().authenticate(tc, ap).withDefaultSubscription();
    }
    return this.arm;
  }
}

// MyClass.java
public class MyClass implements InitializingBean {
  private AzureResourceManagerWrapper azureWrapper;

  public MyClass(AzureResourceManagerWrapper azureWrapper) {
    this.azureWrapper = azureWrapper;
  }

  public List retrieveInstanceDnsList(){
    // Do bad things
  }
}

// MyClassTest.java
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import com.azure.core.management.AzureEnvironment;
import com.azure.core.management.profile.AzureProfile;
import com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

//...
//...
//...

public class MyClassTest {
  AzureResourceManagerWrapper armWrapperMock;
  MyClass myClass;
  ArgumentCaptor<AzureProfile> profileCaptor;
  ArgumentCaptor<ChainedTokenCredential> tokenCaptor;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    armWrapperMock = mock(AzureResourceManagerWrapper.class);
    profileCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(AzureProfile.class);
    tokenCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ChainedTokenCredential.class);
    myClass = new MyClass(armWrapperMock);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMyClass() {
    myClass.retrieveInstanceDnsList(); // Grabs a client using credentials and makes network calls to get DNS list.
    verify(armWrapperMock).getInstance(tokenCaptor.capture(), profileCaptor.capture());

    // TODO Use reflection to verify that all the expected credentials are in the chain.
    ChainedTokenCredential tokenVal = tokenCaptor.getValue();

    // Assert tenantId and subscriptionId set as expected
    AzureProfile profileVal = profileCaptor.getValue();
    assertEquals(TestData.getProperty("server.azure.tenantId"), profileVal.getTenantId());
    assertNull(profileVal.getSubscriptionId());

    // Assert correct Azure cloud
    AzureEnvironment env = EnvironmentInfo.isSomething() ? AzureEnvironment.AZURE_USE_YOUR_IMAGINATION : AzureEnvironment.AZURE;
    assertEquals(env.getEndpoints().get("managementEndpointUrl"), profileVal.getEnvironment().getEndpoints().get("managementEndpointUrl"));
  }
}

// Spring config.xml
<bean id="azureResourceManagerWrapper" class="AzureResourceManagerWrapper" />
<bean id="myClass" class="MyClass">
    <constructor-arg type="AzureResourceManagerWrapper" ref="azureResourceManagerWrapper" />
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- ... -->
/>
```

Comment: Maybe I've been out of the Java game too long but this breaks my brain: `public Object classMethod()` Why would you call an instance (member) method `classMethod`.  I'm guessing it's just a confusing example name but is there more to it?

Comment: It is a confusing name. Let me change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Another thing: I'm not sure where the dependency injection comes in.  Is the idea that you would DI the `TokenCredential` and `AzureProfile` into `AzureResourceManagerWrapperImpl`

Comment: Does the AzureResourceManager class implement an interface?

Comment: To be honest, we have an engineering problem, not a naming problem. It feels like the code structure has its own issues.

Comment: The AzureResourceManager should be initialized in the composition root of your application. A better solution would be to wire it up with a DI container, and simply pass it along as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Along the lines of what Greg has written, one question that I think may be important for the structure is how long this application will be running.  That is, are you sure that the credentials will remain valid for the life of the application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The DI is so that an authenticated AzureResourceManager(Wrapper) is passed to MyClass. It would allow me to write unit tests. It also allows me to centralize when where authentication to Azure is done so that it's not being done more than once unnecessarily.

Comment: The AzureResourceManager does not implement an interface. It is also final and has a private constructor.

Comment: @GregBurghardt would you have an example of how to wire up an AzureResourceManager with a DI container? I'm not the most familiar with the concept of a DI container.

Comment: @JimmyJames the credentials will remain valid for the life of the application. Ironically, that is what led me here. I have to update app code running in a container on AKS to use a WorkloadIdentityCredential that is automatically, periodically refreshed—I have to test code that I update in order to pass CI quality gates.

Comment: Specifically, how can I centralize authentication to Azure Resource Manager in a Spring Java application; and how can I write testable classes that require authenticated instances of AzureResourceManager?

Comment: A coworker suggested I mock one of the static methods on AzureResourceManager. I’m going to try that.